# PHP DomDocument - getElementByID(Partial Match) How?

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementbyid

Is there a way to grab all elements with an id that partially match.  For example, if I want to grab all HTML elements on the webpage with an id attribute that starts with `msg_` but could be anything after that.

Here's what I go so far:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;

// We need to validate our document before refering to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('{URL IS HERE}'));
foreach($doc->getElementById('msg_') as $element) { 
   foreach($element->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
   {
      echo $link->nodeValue . "\n";
   }
}
```

But I need to figure out how to do a partial id match with this bit:  `$doc->getElementById('msg_')` or if there's some other way to accomplish this...??

Basically, I need to grab all 'a' tags that are children of the element with the id starting with `msg_`  Technically there's always, only, going to be 1 `a` tag, but I don't know how to grab just the first Child, which is why I'm using a foreach on this also.

Is this possible with the DomDocument PHP Class?

Here is the code I'm using now, which doesn't work either:

```
$str = '';
$filename = 'http://dream-portal.net/index.php/board,65.0.html';
@set_time_limit(0);

$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $str .= fgets($fp, 16384);
}
fclose($fp);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($str);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$elements = $selector->query('//row[starts-with(@id, "msg_")]');

foreach ($elements as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

HTML is as follows (it's in the `span` tag):

```
<td class="subject windowbg2">
<div>
  <span id="msg_6555">
    <a href="http://dream-portal.net/index.php?topic=834.0">Poll 1.0</a>
  </span>
  <p>
    Started by 
    <a href="http://dream-portal.net/index.php?action=profile;u=1" title="View the profile of SoLoGHoST">SoLoGHoST</a>
    <small id="pages6555">
      « 
      <a class="navPages" href="http://dream-portal.net/index.php?topic=834.0">1</a>
      <a class="navPages" href="http://dream-portal.net/index.php?topic=834.15">2</a>
        »
    </small>

                        with 963 Views

  </p>
</div>
</td>
```

It's the `<span id="msg_` part, and there are a bunch of these (atleast 15 on the HTML page).

Comment: Don't load HTML with loadXML(), use loadHTML()

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have gotten rid of the errors, however, still blank...

Comment: Then I'd suggest posting a part of the HTML as well.

Comment: @Jack - Ok, added in HTML.  It would be too much HTML to post for all of the `<span id="msg_` tags, cause they are spaced really really far apart on the page, but with the same setup as the HTML I posted above at the end of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://dream-portal.net/index.php/board,65.0.html');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($str);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($selector->query('//*[starts-with(@id, "msg_")]') as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Gives you:

```
string(8) "Poll 1.0"
string(12) "Shoutbox 2.2"
string(24) "Polaroid Attachments 1.6"
string(24) "Featured News Slider 1.3"
string(17) "Image Resizer 1.0"
string(8) "Blog 2.2"
string(13) "RSS Feeds 1.0"
string(19) "Adspace Manager 1.2"
string(21) "Facebook Like Box 1.0"
string(15) "Price Table 1.0"
string(13) "SMF Links 1.0"
string(19) "Download System 1.2"
string(16) "[*]Site News 1.0"
string(12) "Calendar 1.3"
string(16) "Page Peel Ad 1.1"
string(20) "Sexy Bookmarks 1.0.1"
string(15) "Forum Staff 1.2"
string(21) "Facebook Comments 1.0"
string(15) "Attachments 1.4"
string(25) "YouTube Channels 0.9 Beta"
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I load an external HTML file from a URL Path into `XPath`??  Can I just do:  `$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('{URL IS HERE}'));`  But I will need to convert the HTML into XML right?

Comment: Use `$str = file_get_contents($your_url);`

Comment: This doesn't work, tested it and I get nothing, just blank content.

Comment: I guess you have not executed **my** example. And just this. Nothing more!....  About `just blank content` : are you aware of getting error messages in PHP? if not, please google this

Comment: Ok, I am seeing this problem now:  `File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (4096)` how to resolve this?

Comment: create a folder like `'C:\uploads'` (note the short path). and use it. Btw, which system are you using?

Comment: Btw, I don't get why this should be related to your question?

Comment: Ok, so I managed to get it all to upload, but am still getting blank... and now a ton of error messages that state something like this:  `DOMDocument::loadXML() [<a href='domdocument.loadxml'>domdocument.loadxml</a>]: Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity`  Do I have to escapse html entities somehow?

Comment: read your question and then my answer. is your problem resolved now? or do you need a personal assistant? If yes we should talk about cash!

Comment: Ok, you try to use your code on this url and tell me what you get:  `http://dream-portal.net/index.php/board,65.0.html`

Comment: But change `row_` to `msg_` instead.

Comment: I have added in the code changes that I made at the bottom of my question... getting tons of html entity errors now!

Comment: +1 for putting up with this :) btw, op is regarding HTML not XML.

Comment: OMG, that did it!!  WoW, very simple and a lot shorter than your original answer!!!  THANKS SO MUCH!  And thanks for putting up with me...